# Mantaflow Sim Not Showing up in Final Render [2.83 Alpha]

Tags: rendering

I've spent a few hours on google/stack exchange/reddit and somehow can't figure out how to get my mantaflow sim to show up in my final render.

I've baked the data and mesh, set the sim to replay, and everything is set as visible to renderer. When I play the simulation in the viewport renderer it works fine and looks great. But when I try to render and output the image or animation it only shows the fluid emitter - the actual simulation just doesn't appear. When I apply the fluid sim in the modifier stack it appears in the final render, but it just bakes the mesh where it's at with no animation.

I've tried moving my cache to a different folder, starting over with a new simulation, and even tested it on my laptop. I just can't get the fluid to show up. Any help would be appreciated - I'm sure it's a stupid easy fix, but I've spent a few hours on it and just can't figure it out.

Here's the blend file for reference: https://pasteall.org/blend/4a093bb431944141bbda50ed875f1f38

Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable mesh in the domain settings and bake it too?

Answer (score 0):

This rendered for me, see attached zip file.
Only changes l made:

- changed cycles from experimental
- rendered a frame past frame 141 - increased the animation frames to 250 as it seemed at 75, 141 much wasnt coming out of the effector mesh holes , thus increasing the simulation .
- increased the point light strength.
- changed the fluid material to Glass  [ie water look]

File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vuo8yEqGqUA4-DrVcNGuQoPjvgYsHEjg/view?usp=sharing